# Do I need to grant "manage_pages" permissions for an app just to view insights?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to connect to a Facebook app that is requesting following permissions:

- Access profile and posts from instagram business connected to your page
- access insights for the instagram business connected to your page
- ** manage your pages**
- show a list of pages you manage
- access your page and app insights

The purpose of the app is to compile post and profile insight stats. If that is the case, why does it need "manage your pages" permission, which gives permission to manage/post/change my page settings?? Or is that legitimately needed just to analyze insights?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/insights#reading

Reading page insights requires a page access token, and the only way to get a page access token is to have a page admin grant `manage_pages` permission to the app first.

`manage_pages` is the baiscpermission to grant an app access to anything related to a page.

So yes, that an app that analyzes your page insight data asks for this permission, is legit. Of course you will have to trust it, that it won’t abuse it for anything else.

It won’t be able to post in your page’s name though, that would require `publish_pages` permission as well.